# How to find linear regression on all combinations of columns using data.table

Tags: r, data.table, regression

I am trying to find the linear regression between groups of the `iris` dataset for each possible combination of variables. Since this is a toy example, it is easy to do the linear regression for each variable set separately and join the results. However, with a `data.table` having a large number of columns, it is difficult to find the linear regression between all groups.

```
library(data.table)
  dt = copy(iris)
  setDT(dt)[, .(model1 = lm(Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Width, .SD)$coeff[2], model2 = lm(Petal.Width ~ Sepal.Length, .SD)$coeff[2]), by = Species]
      Species    model1     model2
1:     setosa 0.9301727 0.08314444
2: versicolor 1.4263647 0.20935719
3:  virginica 0.6508306 0.12141646

  setDT(dt)[, .(model1 = lm(Sepal.Width ~ Petal.Length, .SD)$coeff[2], model2 = lm(Petal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, .SD)$coeff[2]), by = Species]
      Species    model1    model2
1:     setosa 0.3878739 0.0814112
2: versicolor 0.3743068 0.8393782
3:  virginica 0.2343482 0.6863153

  setDT(dt)[, .(model1 = lm(Sepal.Width ~ Sepal.Length, .SD)$coeff[2], model2 = lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, .SD)$coeff[2]), by = Species]
      Species    model1    model2
1:     setosa 0.7985283 0.6904897
2: versicolor 0.3197193 0.8650777
3:  virginica 0.2318905 0.9015345

  setDT(dt)[, .(model1 = lm(Petal.Width ~ Petal.Length, .SD)$coeff[2], model2 = lm(Petal.Length ~ Petal.Width, .SD)$coeff[2]), by = Species]
      Species    model1    model2
1:     setosa 0.2012451 0.5464903
2: versicolor 0.3310536 1.8693247
3:  virginica 0.1602970 0.6472593
```

Rather than doing the linear regression for each set of variables separately, is it possible to do it rather easily using data.table? The output I want is as follows -

```
      Species   Variable1   Variable2     model1     model2
       setosa Sepal.Length  Petal.Width   0.9301727 0.08314444
   versicolor Sepal.Length  Petal.Width   1.4263647 0.20935719
    virginica Sepal.Length  Petal.Width   0.6508306 0.12141646
       setosa Sepal.Width   Petal.Length  0.3878739 0.0814112
   versicolor Sepal.Width   Petal.Length  0.3743068 0.8393782
    virginica Sepal.Width   Petal.Length  0.2343482 0.6863153
       setosa Sepal.Width   Sepal.Length  0.7985283 0.6904897
   versicolor Sepal.Width   Sepal.Length  0.3197193 0.8650777
    virginica Sepal.Width   Sepal.Length  0.2318905 0.9015345
       setosa Petal.Width   Petal.Length  0.2012451 0.5464903
   versicolor Petal.Width   Petal.Length  0.3310536 1.8693247
    virginica Petal.Width   Petal.Length  0.1602970 0.6472593
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We may use `combn` to create a `list` of formulas with `reformulate` on the column names of 'iris' except the 'Species', then , loop over the `list` grouped by 'Species' in the data, apply the `lm` and extract the `coeff`icients

```
library(data.table)
lst1 <- combn(names(iris)[-5], 2, FUN = 
      function(x) reformulate(x[1], x[2]), simplify = FALSE)
dt = copy(iris)
out <- setDT(dt)[, lapply(lst1, function(fmla) 
        lm(fmla, .SD)$coeff), 
       by = Species]
setnames(out, -1, sapply(lst1, deparse))
```

-output

```
out
      Species Sepal.Width ~ Sepal.Length Petal.Length ~ Sepal.Length Petal.Width ~ Sepal.Length Petal.Length ~ Sepal.Width Petal.Width ~ Sepal.Width
1:     setosa                 -0.5694327                   0.8030518                -0.17022108                  1.1829224                0.02417907
2:     setosa                  0.7985283                   0.1316317                 0.08314444                  0.0814112                0.06470856
3: versicolor                  0.8721460                   0.1851155                 0.08325571                  1.9349223                0.16690570
4: versicolor                  0.3197193                   0.6864698                 0.20935719                  0.8393782                0.41844560
5:  virginica                  1.4463054                   0.6104680                 1.22610837                  3.5108983                0.66405950
6:  virginica                  0.2318905                   0.7500808                 0.12141646                  0.6863153                0.45794906
   Petal.Width ~ Petal.Length
1:                -0.04822033
2:                 0.20124509
3:                -0.08428835
4:                 0.33105360
5:                 1.13603130
```